# How to find the bounds of a double integral using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on how to find the bounds for a double integral using polar.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What is the radius of the semicircle? But you wrote that $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $1$; that clearly is incorrect. Use the meaning of $\theta$ in your picture.

Comment: **Hint**: The polar angle $\varphi$ (or $\theta$ in your notation) is positive if it is measured counterclockwise from the polar axis, otherwise it is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing $\theta = 0^\circ$ along the $x$-axis, your semi-circle goes from $\theta = -90^\circ$ to $\theta = 90^\circ$, so that the domain of integration is given by
$$
\begin{align}
R &= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;|\; x^2 + y^2 \le 8, x \ge 0\} \\
  &= \left\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;|\; 0 \le r \le \sqrt{8}, -\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}
\end{align}
$$
hence the following integral :
$$
\int_0^\sqrt{8}r\,\mathrm{d}r \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}\theta\, \sqrt{81-r^2}
$$